# Is > allowed inside XML element's content

Tags: xml, specifications

Looking at definition of [XML element contet](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#NT-content) and it's definition of [CharData](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#NT-CharData).

```
[43] content   ::= CharData? ((element | Reference | CDSect | PI | Comment) CharData?)*

[14] CharData  ::= [^<&]* - ([^<&]* ']]>' [^<&]*)
```

I noticed that this definition of CharData does not forbid having `>` character inside XML element. I assumed this is error so I looked at the description of CharData (emphasis mine)

> The ampersand character (&) and the left angle bracket (<) MUST NOT
>   appear in their literal form, except when used as markup delimiters,
>   or within a comment, a processing instruction, or a CDATA section. If
>   they are needed elsewhere, they MUST be escaped using either numeric
>   character references or the strings "`&amp;`" and "`&lt;`" respectively.
>   **The right angle bracket (>) may be represented** using the string
>   **"`&gt;`"**, and MUST, for compatibility, be escaped using either "`&gt;`" or
>   a character reference when it appears in the string "]]>" in content,
>   when that string is not marking the end of a CDATA section.

So it seems that the [14] and the defintion of CharData are at odds. Is this assumption correct or do parsers allow for `>` inside element without escaping it? Or do they automatically escape it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The character `>` is in fact allowed within xml without escaping, but the character sequence `]]>` is not.

You **MAY** escape any `>` character as `&gt;`, but you **MUST** do so if it is part of the above sequence, i.e., the sequence `]]&gt;` (or the equivalent with a character reference) is the correct way to represent that character sequence in xml when it's not used as the ending mark for a CDATA section.

Comment: So I could technically write `<a>?></a>`? That seems highly weird. I assume what the specification doesn't say yes, then that is forbidden.

Comment: Yes, `<a>?></a>` is valid xml.

Comment: Since this question is being deliberately picky about the spec, I'll point out that `<a>?></a>` is indeed _well-formed_ but we don't know whether or not it's _valid_ unless we have a DTD.

Comment: I wasn't so concerned with validity, but thanks for that note.